# Call jQuery inside function from another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scripting

I am working on wordpress template in which there is a script.js file which is look like below

**script.js**

```
var jQuery=jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

//while window loads
var obj = document.getElementById("centreFrame");
var comObj = document.getElementById("communityFrame");


var side1 = document.getElementById("t3-sidebar-1");
var side2 = document.getElementById("t3-content");

  function getUrlParameter(name, url) {
      if (!url) url = window.location.href;
      name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
      var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
          results = regex.exec(url);
      if (!results) return null;
      if (!results[2]) return '';
      return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
});
```

Now there is another script file "main.js" in which I want to call `getUrlParameter(a,b)` function.

**main.js**

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  //here I need to call getUrlParameter function 
}
```

How can I call "getUrlParameter" function inside this onscroll function ?

NOTE : script.js is loaded first then main.js and also I am not using any bundling tool. If I write this function outside the document ready then it cannot be used inside document ready function.

Comment: did you called? what problem you faced?Make sure `script.js` added before `main.js`

Comment: If you are not using any bundling tool like `webpack`, your `getUrlParameter` should be a global function and should be available in *main.js*. If you are, either you can create a util and bleed this to global scope or create a module and use `import`

Comment: Not using any bundling tool but not get called

Comment: @KushalJain  you din't answer to my comment

Comment: I edited my question already. In main.js, inside window.onscroll function need to call getParamterUrl function but not able to call. scriptjs load first then main.js load. @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 0):

basically you declaring this function getUrlParameter after the document is ready you need to declare it when file is loaded so you need to put this function

```
function getUrlParameter(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

}
outside the the document ready function 
that will fix your issue.

Comment: If I do it like this then I dont able to use inside ready function

Comment: if you put outside the ready function then it declared globally so you can access it anywhere you want

Answer (score 0):

make sure you include both the script files in the html like below and make sure the order is like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
```

Move out function out of the jQuery.document.ready scope and try if it works for you.